# how can'i use local notification in cordova mobile app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I develop a mobile application with cordova, java script and I can not use local notification rather I do not know how to use it or how to proceed. in my application I consume a webservice that sends me data and I would like to notify my users if the data changes. I need your help please.

Comment: It's called push notifications and a quick google search will give you all the required information

Comment: Use this plugin. It will work: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications